# What is the least positive integer $n > 1$ such that $x^n$ and $x$ are conjugate, for every $ x\in S_{11}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, symmetric-groups

What is the least positive integer $n > 1$ such that $x^n$ and $x$ are conjugate, for every
$ x\in S_{11}?$

Choose the correct option

$a. 10$

$b. 11$

$c. 12$

$d.13$

**My attempt** :Two elements $x, y \in S_n$ are conjugate if and only if they have the same cycle type.

Now take $y=x^n \implies x$ and $y $ are conjugate if  gcd($|x|,n$)$=1$

If we take $|x|=11$ then least positive integer $n  $ is $10$

I have no idea  how to solve this problem

Comment: I don’t think you understand what the question meant. Is, for *every* $x \in S_{11}$, $x^{10}$ conjugate to $x$? Ask yourself the question when $x^{10}$ is replaced with $x^{11}$, $x^{12}$ and $x^{13}$.

Comment: (1) is any element, other than the identity, conjugate to the identity? (2) is there a non-identity element $x$ such that $x^n$ is the identity, when $n=10$? when $n=11$? etc.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your attempt, you can observe that you need the value of $n$ to be relatively prime to every possible cycle length you can construct in $S_{11}$.